# Java program to create a set of cards until a card of each shape is obtained using Set

Tags: java, hashset

This is what i have done so far:

```
import java.util.*;
class Card
{
    String symbol;
    int number;
}
class Deck
{
    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        HashSet<Card> ts=new HashSet<Card>();
        int count=0;
        Card c=new Card();  
        boolean flag;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a Card: ");
            c.symbol=sc.next();
            c.number=sc.nextInt();
            ts.add(c);
            count++;
            if(ts.contains('a') && ts.contains('b') && ts.contains('c') && ts.contains('d'))
                flag=true;
            else flag=false;
        }while(flag);
        System.out.println("Four Symbols Gathered in "+count+" Cards!");
        System.out.println("Cards in the deck are: ");
        Iterator<Card> it=ts.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {  
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }

}
}
```

I don't understand why i am getting this output-
Enter a Card: 
a
1
Four Symbols Gathered in 1 Cards!
Cards in the deck are:

Why are the cards aren't adding to the set?
The output i should get should be- 
Enter a card :
a 
1
Enter a card :
a 
2
Enter a card :
d 
6
Enter a card :
c 
2
Enter a card :
d 
1
Enter a card :
c 
1
Enter a card :
b 
2
Four symbols gathered in 8 cards.
Cards in Set are :  a 1  b 2  c 2  d 6

Comment: please implement equals and hashcode on the card class

Comment: You cannot re-use an iterator like that.

Comment: Also, your do while, the first time around, it checks doesn't fined any matches and flag gets set to false. Then, to show what cards you have, your iterator has already been used, so `it.hasNext()` is false.

Comment: where should i use hashcode and equals, i don't understand

Comment: I ran your code here and I got the correct output. The only thing I changed to make it easy was putting the Card class within the main class as static. Anyway here is the output. Enter a Card: 
a 1
Four Symbols Gathered in 1 Cards!
Cards in the deck are: 
Deck$Card@a70ad76

Comment: But, the output should be "a 1" instead of Deck$Card@a70ad75